# Why doesn't my PWA postMessage() in the background?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm currently trying to make a `postMessage()` triggered from a push notification work correctly. Currently, I've got a PWA which has Firebase push notifications. When a notification is sent and clicked, the PWA is launched (if it's installed) and a `postMessage()` is sent.
However, the postMessage() doesn't get received by the client. If the app is in the foreground, it works as expected.
If the all is in the background though, it doesn't catch the `postMessage()`. I was wondering if I needed to listen to some kind of load event in my main `sw.js` file before sending the `postMessage()` - but I'm not sure.

My firebase-message-sw.js file is as follows:

```js
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here

    // self.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
      console.log(`page has loaded | load event | firebase-messaging-sw.js`);
      const channel = new BroadcastChannel('sw-messages');
      channel.postMessage({
        title: payload.notification.title,
        body: payload.notification.body,
        image: payload.notification.image,
        // icon: event.notification.icon,

      }, "*")
    // })

})
```

My `sw.js` file is like this:

```js
addEventListener('notificationclick', event => {
  event.notification.close();
  const urlToOpen = new URL("/settings", self.location.origin).href;
  const promiseChain = clients.matchAll({
    type: 'window',
    includeUncontrolled: true
  }).then((windowClients) => {
    let matchingClient = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
      const windowClient = windowClients[i];
      if (windowClient.url === urlToOpen) {
        matchingClient = windowClient;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (matchingClient) {
      return matchingClient.focus();
    } else {
      console.log(`opening new window`);
      return clients.openWindow(urlToOpen);
    }
  });
  event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
  console.log("promiseChain | sw.js");



  const channel = new BroadcastChannel('sw-messages');
  channel.postMessage({
    title: event.notification.title,
    body: event.notification.body,
    image: event.notification.image,
    icon: event.notification.icon,

  })


});
```

NOTE: This all works as required when the website is viewed in a browser, and not a PWA.

Does anyone has any suggestions/recommendations on what I should do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your notification isn't displaying if it's in the background?

Comment: If the app is closed, when the notification is clicked and the app opens, the `postMessage()` doesn't trigger on the app itself.